# Detecting/Ensuring SKB allocation and free

Tags: network-programming, linux-device-driver, network-driver

Usually The sk_buff is allocated by the module(interface to the network driver) developed by me on transmit side through "`alloc_skb`" and given to the network driver. It's basically free'd by the network driver after send.

Is there a way to do the SKB free from my developed module or Is there a way to ensure whether the network driver is freeing skb buff properly?

Comment: What do you mean by saying "the send side"? Because later you distinguish it with "the network driver" and in the end you also use the word "my send side driver". So, could you please clarify what is the "send side" is, and what network driver (running in kernel) you are talking about.

It is very likely that what's you are looking for is `sk_buff` reference counter. You may increment the field `users` in your `sk_buff` to indicate that it's unsafe to free the buffer. The field is http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/skbuff.h#L764 .

Comment: I updated the question properly

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, you may use `skb_get()` to [increment reference counter](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/skbuff.h#L1300) of your buffer on the "send side". This means that as soon as the network driver decides to free the buffer after putting it on wire, it will call a proper function which will decrement the reference counter but it will still remain non-zero (because of your previous `+ 1`), so it won't be freed. Then you will be able to hold the buffer and free it (as you are the last user) whenever you want.

However, if you have a *chain* of `sk_buff`-s, I'm afraid you need to perform `skb_get()` on each segment.

As for your need to make sure that the network driver itself frees the buffer correctly, you may, for example, find the places in the network driver where a buffer is freed on transmit and insert debug printouts. Then recompile, try to interact with the driver in a normal way (i.e. without doing `skb_get()` prior handing the buffer on to the driver) and observe debug printouts appearing in `dmesg`.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to debug in network driver since I have chain of sk-buff-s